# Web service that shows message box

Tags: web-services, visual-studio

I need to create simple web service application. I need to show message box on the pc that runs that service. Is it possible to ask web service to create message box?

Answer (score 0):

No, thats Not possible. But you can create a client application, which consumes that service. Check the condition and display the message box.